# Is there any way to speed up the for loop in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a situation like

```
for(int count = 0; count <= GetNumberOfRecordsFromFile(path) ; count++)
{
    //do stuff with count                    
}
```

In this loop `GetNumberOfRecordsFromFile(path)` method returns the number of records present in the file in hundreds of thousands or more.The issue is that when the for loop is running to do calculation with count , it is slowing down but works fine..I also tried using of `ParallelFor` loop but it creates problem in calculation...Is there any equivalent way to run the for loop to be faster...?

Comment: What is the contents of your `GetNumberOfRecordsFromFile` method? And what kind of operations are you doing inside the loop?

Comment: GetNumberOfRecordsFromFile returns Just the number of records in a text file

Comment: Please post the code inside for loop. Without that there is no way we can figure out the problem with the loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply calculate it once, store in variable and reuse:

```
int numberOfRecords = GetNumberOfRecordsFromFile(path);
for(int count = 0; count <= numberOfRecords; count++)
{
    //do stuff with count                    
}
```

Now, there is definitely no way to "speed up" this loop. It is as simple as possible.

Comment: Or if there's any way, it is to speed up stuff inside loop.

Comment: @dotnetkid We'd stuggle to make this faster //do stuff with count